# reverse editText box to start after no input has made in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have two `editText` boxes. In the `editText` boxes I have by default 0.0 and behind a hint and I have a `OnFocusChangeListener`.

Every time I tap the `editText` box to put a value in, the 0.0 disappear and the hint is visible and the box wait for input, which is OK.

But if I change my mind and change to the second `editText` box(without input to editText box 1) there is just the hint visible in box 1 but i want the value 0.0 to come back if there was no input.

```
final EditText text_box2;
text_box2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fillingPressure);
text_box2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            if (text_box2.getText().toString().compareTo("0.0") == 0) {
                text_box2.setText("");
            }
        }
    }
});

final EditText text_box1;
text_box1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tankVolume);
text_box1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            if (text_box1.getText().toString().compareTo("0.0") == 0) {
                text_box1.setText("");
            }
        }
    }
});
//
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code:

```
    final EditText text_box2;
    text_box2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fillingPressure);
    text_box2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            if (text_box2.getText().toString().compareTo("0.0") == 0) {
                text_box2.setText("");
            }
        }
    }
});

final EditText text_box1;
text_box1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tankVolume);
text_box1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            if (text_box1.getText().toString().compareTo("0.0") == 0) {
                text_box1.setText("");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Try this:

```
        text_box2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fillingPressure);
        input2 = String.valueOf(text_box2.getText());
        text_box2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if ((hasFocus)&&(input2.equals("0.0") || input2.equals(""))) {
                        text_box2.setText("");
                }
                input2 = (String.valueOf(text_box2.getText()));
                if ((!hasFocus) && (input2.equals(""))){
                    text_box2.setText("0.0");
                }
            }
        });

        text_box1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tankVolume);
        input1 = String.valueOf(text_box1.getText());
        text_box1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if ((hasFocus)&&(input1.equals("0.0") || input1.equals(""))) {
                    text_box1.setText("");
                }
                input1 = (String.valueOf(text_box1.getText()));
                if ((!hasFocus) && (input1.equals(""))){
                    text_box1.setText("0.0");
                }

            }
        });
```

Now you need to declare your variables outside of the onCreate method like this:

```
public class YourClass extends Activity {
    String input1, input2;
    EditText text_box1, text_box2;
    // onCreate method here
```

Finally, make sure both your EditText values are set in your .xml to "0.0"

The reason you want to declare the variables outside of the onCreate() method is to avoid making them final. If the variables are final, the value would never change from "0.0".

Let me know if you have any more questions.